# Mapping child objects in fluent nhibernate to a read-only view

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Given that I am implementing a read-only UI, how do I create a ClassMap for `Shop`:

```
public class Shop {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}

public class City {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

The DB interface for Shops is a View containing 3 columns (ShopId, CityName, CountryCode). I was hoping to do something like this:

```
public sealed class ShopMap : ClassMap<Shop> {
    public ShopMap()
    {
        Table("Shop");
        Id(x => x.Id, "ShopId");
        Map(x => x.City.Name, "CityName");
        Map(x => x.City.CountryCode, "CountryCode");
    }
}
```

Will fluent auto-instantiate Shop.City?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a component might be the proper way as described in the [fluent hibernate wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping)